# Insert current Excel workbook name in to a text file

Tags: excel, vba, export

I need to export the current Workbook's name to a specific line/place in a text file using a Macro/VBA Code.

I have Workbooks where the calculations are done externally with Python.
Python uses one config.json file as reference as to which Excel file to do the calculations on.

Every time I want to do calculations on a different workbook I have to manually change the Excel file name in the config.json file.
The config.jason file is in a different Dir than the Excel file.

The Excel file name needs to go in to the "input_file line in the config.jason file
"input_file": "D:\Temp\workbook_name.xlsm"

config.jason file sample content.

```
{
    "columns": {
        "Date": "Date",
        "Product Description": "Description",
        "Category": "Category",
        "ID": "ID",
        "Views": "Stock",
        "PM": "SUMIF",
        "Active Until": "Until",
        "Item Decription": "DES",
        "Item Category": "CAT",
    },
    "input_file": "D:\\Temp\\workbook_name.xlsm"
}
```

Comment: Apart from the workbook path, is the JSON static? Could the JSON file be edited outside this process and if so, how often?

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question... What exactly are you trying to achieve beyond altering some text, how do you want to achieve it and what have you tried already?

Comment: Store the config.json file content in a cell on a worksheet, with a token like (eg) `"<file>"` which you can `Replace()` with the actual file path, before using that content to overwrite the existing config file.

Comment: The JASON file is static.
Can even use a shortcut to the original Jason file is needed.

Comment: I'm only trying to alter text in a file.
I had a look through the forums but could not get something that resembles this scenario.
I have not tried anything because I don't even know how it can be done in VBA. If can do it with Python but that's not a solution in this case.

Comment: Tim Williams.


Can you please elaborate/explain on your reply:
" Store the config.json file content in a cell on a worksheet, with a token like (eg) "<file>"..."

Sounds like a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Build the JSON string and use a FileSystemObject to create the text file.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CreateJSON()

    Const JSONFILE = "config.json"
    Const FOLDER = "path-to-config.json"
    Const NL = vbCrLf & "    " ' new line
    
    Dim dict As Object, k
    Dim json As String, filename As String, comma As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' config
    dict.Add "Date", "Date"
    dict.Add "Product Description", "Description"
    dict.Add "Category", "Category"
    dict.Add "ID", "ID"
    dict.Add "Views", "Stock"
    dict.Add "PM", "SUMIF"
    dict.Add "Active Until", "Until"
    dict.Add "Item Decription", "DES"
    dict.Add "Item Category", "CAT"

    ' filename unix for python
    filename = Replace(ThisWorkbook.FullName, "\", "/")
    
    ' build json string
    json = "{" & NL & """columns"": {"
    For Each k In dict.keys
        json = json & comma & NL & "    """ & k & """: """ & dict(k) & """"
        comma = ","
    Next
    json = json & NL & "}," & NL & """input_file"": """ & filename & """" & vbCrLf & "}"
    
    ' write file
    Dim FSO As Object, ts As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = FSO.CreateTextFile(FOLDER & JSONFILE)
    ts.write json
    ts.Close
    
    MsgBox JSONFILE & " created in " & FOLDER, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you  CDP1802.
I will let you know once I've ran your code/contribution.

Comment: Thank you @CDP1802.
Your code works first time every time.! I tested again and again.
So beautiful when code works :-)

Thank you for your time and effort. This really helps me a lot with project I'm getting of the ground.

Answer (score 0):

In cell A1:

```txt
{
    "columns": {
        "Date": "Date",
        "Product Description": "Description",
        "Category": "Category",
        "ID": "ID",
        "Views": "Stock",
        "PM": "SUMIF",
        "Active Until": "Until",
        "Item Decription": "DES",
        "Item Category": "CAT",
    },
    "input_file": "<file>"
}
```

Code to replace token and create/overwrite json file:

```vb
Sub RefreshJson()

    PutContent "C:\temp\config.json", _
               Replace(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value, "<file>", _
                       Replace(ActiveWorkbook.FullName, "\", "\\"))

End Sub


'create/overwrite a text file at location `f` using `content`
Sub PutContent(f As String, content As String)
    CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  opentextfile(f, 2, True).write content
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim Williams.
I have not tested your code contribution yet. Not rejecting it - I'm just being honest.
I will apply and test as another option.